# Parsing JSON with special characters

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller, flot

I am using flot to do some graphing and I am having some trouble passing the tickSize with my json.  I am using MVC and pass the json in a model.  Here is some code to grab the json within my javascript function:

```
var json = '<%=Model.Json %>';
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
```

Here is how the Json looks leaving the controller:

```
{\"GraphData\":[{\"X\":1333929600000,\"Y\":0.0},{\"X\":1333670400000,\"Y\":0.46}],\"Max\":1333324800000,\"Min\":1333929600000,\"TickSize\":\"[1, 'day']\"}
```

The part that I am having trouble with is "TickSize."  As you can see, "[1, 'day']" has the square brackets.  I think there is some parsing problem because [] usually means an array.  Flot wants the tick size in this format.  How do I construct my Json so I can grab the TickSize?

Comment: I think TickSize is considered a string and not array in JSON because it is quoted. If it wasn't quoted it would be an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the single-quotes in the string value, since you're trying to wrap the JSON string in them as well. The resulting JavaScript will be (truncated):

```
var json = '...,\"TickSize\":\"[1, 'day']\"}';
```

Because of the now 4-count of single-quotes, `day` isn't actually part of the string and creates a syntax error.

But, you shouldn't even need to quote and parse the JSON since it's derived from JavaScript syntax:

```
var data = <%= Model.Json %>;
```

If you need the string representation, you can either stringify it in JavaScript:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(data):
```

Or escape single-quotes within the string server-side:

```
var json = '<%= Model.Json.Replace("'", "\\'") %>';
```

Comment: Or use `JSON.stringify(<%= HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.Json, addDoubleQuotes: true) %>)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have surrounded the string with `'` instead of `"`. This is causing the string to terminate with your first `'`.

Rewrite your first line as

```
var json = "<%=Model.Json %>";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**  replace single backslash '\' with double '\\' back slash.

For Newline character  '\n'  to '\\n'

Works with Tooltip messages