# Issue with encoding a JSON array

Tags: android, json, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have this JSON object I get from server:

```
 [
 {
  "Cliente":"AS' MEIGAS BAR",
  "Direccion":"C\/ Diego La\u00ednez, 8",
  "Telefono":"975 301 451",
  "Microsite":"www.guiacolor.com\/empresa\/772068",
  "URL":"",
  "Latitud":"41.486416",
  "Longitud":"-2.533894",
  "Logo":"http:\/\/www.guiacolor.com\/logo\/772068.gif",
  "Aque":"Bar ubicado en el centro de Almaz\u00e1n",
  "Imagenes":"",
  "ClienteTecnologico":"N",
  "QuienesSomos":"",
  "Mail":"",
  "TipoCliente":"B"
  },
 {
  "Cliente":"BAR AS'MEIGAS",
  "Direccion":"C\/ Diego La\u00ednez, 8 Bajo",
  "Telefono":"975301451",
  "Microsite":"www.guiacolor.com\/empresa\/809905",
  "URL":"",
  "Latitud":"41.553699",
  "Longitud":"-2.519793",
  "Logo":"http:\/\/www.guiacolor.com\/logo\/809905.gif",
  "Aque":"",
  "Imagenes":"",
  "ClienteTecnologico":"N",
  "QuienesSomos":"",
  "Mail":"",
  "TipoCliente":"C"
 },
 {
  "Cliente":"BAR MEIGAS",
  "Direccion":"C\/ Alcalleres, 2",
  "Telefono":"983335395",
  "Microsite":"www.guiacolor.com\/empresa\/735825",
  "URL":"",
  "Latitud":"",
  "Longitud":"",
  "Logo":"http:\/\/www.guiacolor.com\/logo\/735825.gif",
  "Aque":"",
  "Imagenes":"",
  "ClienteTecnologico":"N",
  "QuienesSomos":"",
  "Mail":"",
  "TipoCliente":"D"
  },
 {
  "Cliente":"EL PUCHERO DE LAS MEIGAS",
  "Direccion":"C\/ Monast. San Millan Cogolla, 8",
  "Telefono":"983335555",
  "Microsite":"www.guiacolor.com\/empresa\/751329",
  "URL":"",
  "Latitud":"",
  "Longitud":"",
  "Logo":"http:\/\/www.guiacolor.com\/logo\/751329.gif",
  "Aque":"",
  "Imagenes":"",
  "ClienteTecnologico":"N",
  "QuienesSomos":"",
  "Mail":"",
  "TipoCliente":"D"
 },
 {
  "Cliente":"MEIGAS TAPERIA BAR",
  "Direccion":"C\/ Danier Ortega, 1",
  "Telefono":"921182665",
  "Microsite":"www.guiacolor.com\/empresa\/780705",
  "URL":"",
  "Latitud":"",
  "Longitud":"",
  "Logo":"http:\/\/www.guiacolor.com\/logo\/780705.gif",
  "Aque":"",
  "Imagenes":"",
  "ClienteTecnologico":"N",
  "QuienesSomos":"",
  "Mail":"",
  "TipoCliente":"D"
}
]
```

So, there's an item called

```
AS' MEIGAS BAR
```

and other one called

```
BAR AS'MEIGAS
```

However, in my app, they show up as

```
AS&#039; MEIGAS BAR
```

and

```
BAR AS'MEIGAS
```

Is this some encoding issue? How can it be solved? I've tried to encode it to UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 and I couldn't solve it.

Edit: It's just the first one who gives the `&#039;`, the other one shows allright.

Comment: hope it will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080208/parsing-json-with-special-characters

Comment: What are you doing with those values? *"1. Value OK 2. ??? 3. Messed up"* is kinda hard to answer without knowing what *2. ???* is.

Comment: Right now I'm just getting them as a JSONArray and getting each client as a JSONObject, then listing them.