# How does parsing special characters in JSON work?

Tags: json, parsing

Alright, I know i’m probably going to get yelled at for asking such a ‘simple’ question (seems to be the trend around here) but check it out…

I am building a JSON parser and got everything working correctly except the parsers ability to deal with special characters. I am trying to implement the same special characters that are listed on http://www.json.org/ namely, [", \, /, b, f, n, r, t, u].

When I run these special characters through the builtin JSON.parse method though, most of them either return an error or don’t do anything at all

```
JSON.parse('["\\"]')
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

JSON.parse("['\"']")
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ‘

JSON.parse('["\b"]')
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 

JSON.parse('["\f"]')
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

Yes, I see the other post ["Parsing JSON with special characters"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080208/parsing-json-with-special-characters), it has nothing to do with my question. Don't refer me to another question, I have seen them all. How does parsing special characters in JSON work?

Comment: The backslash codes are being interpreted by javascript. If you want to pass a backslash in a string, you need to escape it. So for JSON.parse to "see" `\n`, for example, you'd need `JSON-parse('["\\n"]')`

Answer (score 1):

JSON.parse expects JavaScript strings.

JavaScript string literals use backslashes for escaping.

JSON uses backslashes for escaping.

So...

```
JSON.parse('["\\\\"]')
// ["\"]

JSON.parse("['\"']")
// SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
// JSON doesn't have single quotes as string delimiters!

JSON.parse('["\\b"]')
// [""]

JSON.parse('["\\f"]')
// [""]

JSON.parse('["\\\\b"]')
// ["\b"]

JSON.parse('["\\\\f"]')
// ["\f"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you've got an issue here is because `\` is also a marker for special characters within javascript strings.

Take your first example: `'["\\"]'`. As javascript parses this string, `\\` is escaped to a single `\` in your string, so the value passed to `JSON.parse` method is actually `["\"]` - hence the "unexpected end of input error".

Essentially, you need to cater for the javascript parser by doubling-up on the backslash escape sequences. In this case, to pass your intended `["\\"]` value to `JSON.parse`, you need to use `JSON.parse('["\\\\"]')` in javascript as that will pass the string `["\\"]` into the `JSON.parse` method.