# Convert to JS Object

Tags: javascript, json, connect-flash

How to convert this to JS object:

```
{&quot;info&quot;:[&quot;Image has been added&quot;],&quot;success&quot;:[&quot;No success Sorry!&quot;]}
```

JSON.parse throws an error and says &quot isn't valid JSON. Am new to JS and can't figure out how to deal with this.

I am using connect-flash from express to transfer flash messages to the client side. For doing so, I am using the following code:

```
if Object.keys(locals.flashes).length !== 0
    script.
      flashArr="#{JSON.stringify(locals.flashes)}"
```

On the client side, the representation of the Object isn't valid JSON. How can I handle this.

Comment: Cannot replicate, no errors here https://jsfiddle.net/83vhvv5e/

Comment: `{"info":["Image has been added"],"success":["No success Sorry!"]}` this is an valid js object already, doesn't require to be convert

Comment: there is no `&quot` in what you posted - so clearly what you posted is **not** what you are working with - `&quot;` is the HTMLEntitity known as `"`

Comment: An error is there when I use JSON.stringify(locals.flashes) and get the variable on the client side. Then when using JSON.parse(flashArr), I get the error

Comment: {&quot;info&quot;:[&quot;Image has been added&quot;],&quot;success&quot;:[&quot;No success Sorry!&quot;]}

Comment: aha, now we see the culprit - that's not JSON

Comment: Plz check it now. The editor had converted into a simple sentence

Comment: But that is what i get on using JSON.stringify on flashArr

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080208/parsing-json-with-special-characters

Comment: No it is not, that's what happens once it is sent/received (not sure which end is doing this) ... check this out though `var x = document.createElement('div'); x.innerHTML = '{&quot;info&quot;:[&quot;Image has been added&quot;],&quot;success&quot;:[&quot;No success Sorry!&quot;]}'; console.log(JSON.parse(x.textContent))` - may help you, but as you've shown very little actual code, I can't do better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, you need to parse the HTML entities to characters, i.e. convert `&quot;` to `"`. The simplest way is to use a regular expression:

```js
var str = '{&quot;info&quot;:[&quot;Image has been added&quot;],&quot;success&quot;:[&quot;No success Sorry!&quot;]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(str.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));
console.log(obj);
```

Of course if you have other HTML entities in the code it might be better to use the built-in HTML parser:

```js
var str = '{&quot;info&quot;:[&quot;Image has been added&quot;],&quot;success&quot;:[&quot;No success Sorry!&quot;]}';

var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = str;

var obj = JSON.parse(el.textContent);
console.log(obj);
```

But for a single entity, *replace* is likely faster and more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

**How to convert this to JS object?**

If I try like this it returns me valid JS object. I just globally replaced the `&quot;` with `""` using [String.prototyp.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and then parse it using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) like this

```js
invalid_data = '{&quot;info&quot;:[&quot;Image has been added&quot;],&quot;success&quot;:[&quot;No success Sorry!&quot;]}';
valid_data = invalid_data.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
console.log(JSON.parse(valid_data));
```